# Make a python script run for exactly 30 hours

Tags: python, loops, time, server

I have a python script that logs data:

```
Time: 2016-06-17 13:08:11.282284 - Histogram: 0.431836079339
Time: 2016-06-17 13:08:11.416480 - Histogram: 0.431577614379
Time: 2016-06-17 13:08:11.533433 - Histogram: 0.431303002451
Time: 2016-06-17 13:08:11.653146 - Histogram: 0.425248621324
Time: 2016-06-17 13:08:11.790831 - Histogram: 0.425051657816
Time: 2016-06-17 13:08:11.932212 - Histogram: 0.425085608433
Time: 2016-06-17 13:08:12.058576 - Histogram: 0.425135206745
```

And I've been studying server usage. Now, I can run a file on a server just fine, but my question is how do I set up a function so that the script runs for exactly 30 hours, and then quits?

I have an idea of how it might work; I could count the number of seconds, but I was wondering if there was a quick/easy way of implementing a timed loop in python?

Comment: How are you acquiring the data to log? It seems like to might be easier to have a single run of the script get your "latest" data, and make a `cron` or similar job to run the script repeatedly over 30 hours.

Comment: A timer thread looks like it would do what you want: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Comment: How accurate do you need to be? How long does a single run of the script take?

Comment: @ali_m the script runs continually, it doesn't stop. I need at least 1400 minutes of data.

Comment: Thanks, @christopher-schneider. I'll check that out.

Comment: `start = time.time(); while (time.time() - start) < 30*60*60: # do stuff`